# Outgoing SMTP Username reverts

Tags: settings, smtp

After having filled in all setting for outgoing SMTP (using gmail) I fail to send email. The error from GMail says that the settings are incorrect (most likely). And indeed, even when I set my GMail account name in "Outgoing SMTP Username" upon clicking save and test it seems to revert to my Joomla logged in account name.

That is:

- I enter **foo@bar.com** in the textbox, click save. (and all other
  settings ... duh!)
- I leave that page.
- I return to outgoing server settings.
- Now I see foo@bar.com in Outgoing SMTP Username for a split  second,
  then it reverts to my user account so that when I attempt to send
  and test the settings it has MYLOGGEDINUSERNAME as the Outgoing SMTP Username

The specific error message is: Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: -1, response: )]

How do I fix this?

Joomla 3.7.5
Latest CiviCRM

Comment: This seems to be browser related. Chrome does this, Edge doesn't.

Comment: I almost went crazy over this just now. Thanks for pointing to the culprit, Chrome. Although perhaps there might be away to prevent it.